# Bolero datetime bind

Tags: f#, elmish, bolero

The [docs](https://fsbolero.io/docs/HTML#data-bindings) say that you can bind many different data types...

My html template:

```
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Dob</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input class="input" type="date" placeholder="Date of Birth..." bind="${Dob}">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my code is:

```
  .Dob(model.client.dob, fun n -> dispatch (SetDob n))
```

But I get a red underline on `model.client.dob` because it's expecting a string.... what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's probably something like this?

```ml
        .Dob(
            model.client.dob.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
            fun n -> 
                let dt = DateTimeOffset.Parse(n)
                dispatch (SetDob dt)
        )
```

I would have thought that was built in... from how the docs talk about